# Codeigniter not properly processing a foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got about 10 rows in my db and 3 of which have status == to 'Pass'. The problem I've noticed with the code below is with the foreach loop. It's not wanting to work properly. I can't even get the script to send the jSON data back to the browser which means the script isn't processing past the foreach statement. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
public function logsig() {
        header('Content-type:application/json');
        $postedUser = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $hashedPass = $this->encrypt->sha1($password);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$postedUser}' AND password = '{$hashedPass}'");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($row->status == "Pass") {
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged', "1");
                    $this->session->set_userdata("username", "{$postedUser}");
                    echo json_encode(array('session_state' => true));
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('session_state' => false));
                }
            } elseif ($row->status == "Fail" || "Pending") {
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning any results?

Comment: No right now it's not returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're echoing the JSON in each iteration of the loop.  This will make something like this:

```
{"session_state": true}{"session_state": false}
```

This is not valid JSON.

You need to build an array, and then `echo json_encode()` (just once) after the loop.

Also your `elseif` should be this:

```
elseif ($row->status == "Fail" || $row->status == "Pending")
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that in the response header when i coded it a different way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `elseif ($row->status == "Fail" || "Pending") {` with

`elseif ($row->status == "Fail" || $row->status == "Pending") {`

You are missing `$row->status ==` in your second condition of elseif block